Open browsers with no or only the specific plugins enabled?
As title. Wondering how these are done:
TrendMicro Pay Guard
Kaspersky Safe Money
Currently looking for a way to open "safe browser" window without external tools like Sandboxie likewise. Mainly for Windows OS.
Perhaps there's something I missed? Thanks in advance for any help.
I did tried chromium --disable-plugins switch option, but it doesn't work like what I experienced with aboves. Plugins are getting re-initialized while being reopened with the --disable-plugins switch removed.
